# Energy savings with cloud computing using cisco packet tracer

Tags: cloud, cisco, energy

I am new to cisco packet tracer. I need to set up a large network with multiple routers and pcs and monitor the energy consumption when a pc communicates with another and compare the energy consumption with a network that has clouds instead of traditional servers. 
Do you know if there is a way to do that using cisco packet tracer? Thank you in advance

Answer (score -1):

No, there is no way to measure power consumption using packet tracer.

Comment: Do you happen to know another free software that can do that?

Comment: I guess your best option would be to estimate the consumption using data sheets, but please note that the energy consumption depends on the device configuration and load. For example, please look at this table: https://learningnetwork.cisco.com/thread/14354 Depending on the throughput the measured power is different.